# MVC3 - How to Exclude the hidden columns of the Dhtmlxgrid in the excel file

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc-3, dhtmlx

Is there anyway, to exclude the hidden columns of the DhtmlxGrid in the excel file?

Right now when I do export to excel, it also includes the column which are hidden in the excel. Please suggest.

```
MVC3
in View: 
on a button click my code:

_grid.toExcel('@Url.Content("~/Shared/ExportGridToExcel?TableName")' +'Doc');

in Controller:

 public ActionResult ExportGridToExcel(string TableName)
        {
            var generator = new ExcelWriter();
            var xml = this.Request.Form["grid_xml"];
            xml = this.Server.UrlDecode(xml);
            var stream = generator.Generate(xml);
            return File(stream.ToArray(), generator.ContentType, TableName + ".xls");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Find this method and replace this

```
    public ActionResult GenerateExcel()
    {
        var generator = new ExcelWriter();
        var xml = this.Request.Form["grid_xml"];
        xml = this.Server.UrlDecode(xml);
        var xmlObj = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        foreach (var x in xmlObj.Descendants("columns").ElementAt(0).Descendants("column"))
        {
            var w = x.Attribute("width").Value;
            if (Convert.ToString(w).Equals("0")) { x.SetAttributeValue("hidden", "true"); }
        }
        xml = xmlObj.ToString();
        var stream = generator.Generate(xml);
        return File(stream.ToArray(), generator.ContentType, "grid.xlsx");
    }
```

Dont forget to mark this as answer if it works

Answer (score 0):

Use setColumnHidden api to hide column before export call, and show the column after it. Hidden columns do not included in the export result.